# Material-ui toolbar with expendable section

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What component is used for material-ui expandable section for code?
I can't find the same element, and card is not exactly what I need (different style)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Found sources here. https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/app/components/CodeExample

And some text to make the anwer 30 chars